# count words without point and comma in python

Tags: python

I would like to count each word in a text file in python.

My text is this

```
Aragon is an autonomous community in northeastern Spain. The capital of Aragon is Zaragoza, which is also the most populous city in the autonomous community. Covering an area of ​​47720 km2, the region's terrain ranges from permanent glaciers through verdant valleys, rich pastures and orchards to the arid steppe plains of the central lowlands. Aragon is home to many rivers, most notably the Ebro, Spain's largest river, which flows west to east throughout the region through the province of Zaragoza. It is also home to the highest mountains in the Pyrenees.
```

I gave the following code

```
file=open("data/aragon.txt",'r')
from collections import Counter
wordcount = Counter(file.read().split())
for item in wordcount.items(): print("{}\t{}".format(*item))
```

But the problem is, it doesnt come in an order. I would like to have that the highest is at the top and lowest on the other side and don't have any words like this: Ebro, or Spain. no point or comma just word

How can I fix that?

Comment: Preprocess your str: downcase, remove unwanted chars, etc.  Collections are unordered unless you order them: see the docs.

Comment: Are you looking for total length para with special charters ?

Comment: I am looking, how often for example Spain occurs in this text file, but only Spain without point. (not Spain.)

Comment: Counter has a kind of [sort method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use regex and match words

```
from collections import Counter
import re
wordcount = Counter(re.findall('\w+', file.read()))
for item in wordcount.most_common(): print("{}\t{}".format(*item))
```

Comment: Yes, this is good, but how can I order it with highest occurence at the top and lowest on the other side?

Comment: use `wordcount.most_common()` outputs a with highest occurence at the top and lowest at the end

Answer (score 1):

You might use [`.isalnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isalnum#str.isalnum) method to check if character is letter or digit, for simplicity I will use part of your text stored in variable, as opposed to reading whole from file

```
import collections
aragon = "Aragon is an autonomous community in northeastern Spain. The capital of Aragon is Zaragoza, which is also the most populous city in the autonomous community. Covering an area of ​​47720 km2."
aragon_cleaned = ''.join(char if char.isalnum() else ' ' for char in aragon)
print(aragon_cleaned)
```

gives output

```
Aragon is an autonomous community in northeastern Spain  The capital of Aragon is Zaragoza  which is also the most populous city in the autonomous community  Covering an area of 47720 km2
```

observe that `,` and `.` were replaced by spaces, double space is not problem, because `.split()` does split at one-or-more whitespaces. For getting elements from popoular to least you might use [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method like so

```
for word, count in collections.Counter(aragon_cleaned.split()).most_common():
    print(word,'occured',count,'times')
```

gives output

```
is occured 3 times
Aragon occured 2 times
an occured 2 times
autonomous occured 2 times
community occured 2 times
in occured 2 times
of occured 2 times
the occured 2 times
northeastern occured 1 times
Spain occured 1 times
The occured 1 times
capital occured 1 times
Zaragoza occured 1 times
which occured 1 times
also occured 1 times
most occured 1 times
populous occured 1 times
city occured 1 times
Covering occured 1 times
area occured 1 times
47720 occured 1 times
km2 occured 1 times
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import re
file = open("t1.txt", "rt")
data = file.read()
[re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', _).lower() for _ in data.split(' ')].count('is')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from collections import Counter

file=open("data/aragon.txt",'r')
text_punctuation = r"[\.,;:!\|\?\x0c\_\"'\{\}\[\]\(\)=\-+/<>]" 
t = re.sub(text_punctuation, " ", txt)
wordcount = Counter(t.split(' '))
for item in wordcount.items(): print("{}\t{}".format(*item)) 
 
Output:
Aragon  3
is  5
an  2
autonomous  2
community   2
in  3
northeastern    1
Spain   2
    11
The 1
capital 1
of  4
Zaragoza    2
which   2
also    2
the 10
most    2
populous    1
city    1
Covering    1
area    1
47720   1
km2 1
region  2
s   2
terrain 1
ranges  1
from    1
permanent   1
glaciers    1
through 2
verdant 1
valleys 1
rich    1
pastures    1
and 1
orchards    1
to  4
arid    1
steppe  1
plains  1
central 1
lowlands    1
home    2
many    1
rivers  1
notably 1
Ebro    1
largest 1
river   1
flows   1
west    1
east    1
throughout  1
province    1
It  1
highest 1
mountains   1
Pyrenees    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `wordcount.most_common()` instead of `wordcount.items()`

```
from collections import Counter
wordcount = Counter(file.read().split())
for item in wordcount.most_common(): print("{}\t{}".format(*item))
```

> on the other side and don't have any words like this: Ebro

Actually you have.

Comment: most notably the Ebro,